# Number of working days remaining this month

Tags: excel-formula

I am using this formula to show the number of days remaining this month. Is it possible to do this for number of working days?

```
=EOMONTH(TODAY(),0)-TODAY()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Analysis Toolpack also provides the function NETWORKDAYS to find the number of working days between two dates.

NETWORKDAYS(start_date,end_date,holidays)

Comment: How would you modify =EOMONTH(TODAY(),0)-TODAY() to produce number of remaining working days this month?

Comment: Like this =NETWORKDAYS(TODAY(),EOMONTH(TODAY(),0))

Answer (score 0):

```
=networkdays(given_date,eomonth(given_date,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is example:

```js
function daysInMonth(month, year) {
  return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
}

MonthDays = daysInMonth(6, 2016);
today = new Date();
day = today.getDate();
remainingDaysInMonth = MonthDays - day;
console.log(remainingDaysInMonth)
```